# Play Framework Call a template in href

Tags: playframework, template-engine

Is there a way to call a play framework view template in the a href tag? Something in the lines of:

```
<a href="my.template.scala.html">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Why would you want to bypass controller and go straight to view when following that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use reverse routing to get the URL for a controller. If the controller doesn't need do anything it can just be really simple like (this is for Play 2 Scala):

```
Action {
  Ok(views.html.my.template)
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this actually, but I thought I could bypass the controller.